# Keras OOM error while fine-tuning but not while training

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gpu

I have a autoencoder model that I initialized and trained on a GPU machine with 128x128 sized-images dataset and a batch-size of 64. I saved the trained model file. Then I load this saved model file and restart training on a new dataset with 128x128 sized-images and batch-size of 64. But I get an OOM error this time. When the scenario is exactly same as before, why is it throwing an OOM error? (The GPU memory is 0% used every time I start training).

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but have you tried limiting the memory growth with `tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')[0], True)` ?

Comment: Yes, I have used the memory growth option.

Comment: please show code for data input and what you did after model was trained the first time, ie code you used to fine tune model